# how to bind the value of a variable to another variable in php

Tags: php, variables, session, bind

I have 3 arrays:

```
$q1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
$q2 = ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H'];
$q3 = ['I', J', 'K', 'L'];
```

When i click on submit in a form, i store a session and everytime i click on `next`, the session will increment with `1`

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['i']))  {
    $_SESSION['i'] = 0;
}
if(isset($_POST['next'])){
    $_SESSION['i']++;       
}

$session = $_SESSION['i'];
echo $session;
```

Now i want to bind the value of the session to the variable `$q`

So after 1 submit, `$q` must become `$q1`, after second submit; `$q` must become `$q2` and so on...

So everytime i submit, the value of the session must be bind to `$q`, so that i can read different arrays.

(I want to use this for creating a dynamic form:)

```
foreach ($q as $key => $value) {
...
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of variables - **use array**:

```
// I use explicit indexing, as you start with `i = 1`
$q = [
    1 => ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    2 => ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H'],
    3 => ['I', 'J', 'K', 'L'],
];

$_SESSION['i'] = 3;
print_r($q[$_SESSSION['i']]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code already looks fine and almost done.

So I use another `array`, which stores all your other `arrays`.

If you now get your `$session` variable, you can access the wrapper array and get your specific array you want. As you started your array names with 1, but arrays getting called with starting index 1, you have to subtract - 1.

```
$q1 = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D');
$q2 = array('E', 'F', 'G', 'H');
$q3 = array('I', 'J', 'K', 'L');

$wrapper = array($q1, $q2, $q3);

$session = 2;

foreach ($wrapper[$session-1] as $key) {
 //Will output E, F , G H as session is =2
 echo $key;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Recommended**

You can use PHP array to do this.

```php
$arr = [
    1 => ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    2 => ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H'],
    3 => ['I', J', 'K', 'L'],
];
```

then, access it like:

```php
print_r($arr[$_SESSION['i']]);
```

Not ready to use `Arrays`?Well, PHP also allows you to use dynamic variable names, called **Variable variables**.

```php
$variableName = "q";
//..... Update the value of i in session.

 $variableName .= $_SESSION['i'];// when i = 1, it becomes q1;

 print_r($$variableName); // notice the $$ in the Variable Name
 // output
 // Array (0 => 'A', 1 => 'B', 2 => 'C', 3 => 'D')
```

> Read more about Variable Variables here
>   https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php